# Rds(on) value of MOSFET constant current LED driver IC

Tags: mosfet, led, integrated-circuit, driver, constant-current

I am testing a non-isolated APFC buck constant-current LED driver IC (model no.: BP2362XH) in my LED driver circuit. It operates in critical conduction mode (according to the datasheet). There are a few variations of this IC. In my application, I want to use this IC to get 120 mA DC current through LEDs.

BP2362BH R<sub>DS(on)</sub> = 9 Ω, drain-source breakdown voltage = 500 V

BP2362CH R<sub>DS(on)</sub> = 5.8 Ω, drain source breakdown voltage = 500 V

BP2362EH R<sub>DS(on)</sub> = 3 Ω, drain source breakdown voltage = 500 V

BP2362GH R<sub>DS(on)</sub> = 1.9 Ω, drain source breakdown voltage = 500 V

BP2362JH R<sub>DS(on)</sub> = 1.9 Ω, drain source breakdown voltage = 600 V

Please explain which IC is more suitable for my application based on R<sub>DS(on)</sub>.

Input AC voltage for LED driver is 230 V.

Comment: Please link the data sheets for the devices and show the circuit you propose to use.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i5t2hpevszJwQR4jiHDpurmf70B7V6ge/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you and please check above data sheet (which includes a circuit diagram)

Answer (score 0):

If they are all the same price, the lowest R<sub>DS(on)</sub> is the best. But if that's the most expensive, and if cost matters, read on.

So you have a load of 120mA. The heat generated by the chip will be 120mA * 120mA * R<sub>DS(on)</sub> + quiescent + chip supply power. Lets forget about those last 2 terms as they will be a small fraction of the heat generated. Here's what the MOSFET heat generation looks like:

- 9 Ω: 130 mW
- 5.8 Ω: 84 mW
- 3 Ω: 43 mW
- 1.9 Ω: 27 mW

Now, you look at the thermal data: PDMax (absolute maximum power dissipation) and (theta)JA (thermal resistance of the junction to ambient). Also note the "note 2" in that section as it provides the math we are going to need.

Based on your load, you are under the maximum power dissipation of 450 mW. All good there. The next thing is to check the expected temperature rise based on your load:

- 9 Ω: 130 mW * 145 °C/W = 18.9°C temp rise
- 5.8 Ω: 84 mW * 145 °C/W = 12.2°C temp rise
- 3 Ω: 43 mW * 145 °C/W = 6.2°C temp rise
- 1.9 Ω: 27 mW * 145 °C/W = 3.9°C temp rise

These temperature rises are the temperature increases of the junction over the ambient temperature.

So now, take the maximum permissible junction temperature - 150°C. Subtract the Max from the temp rise:

- 9 Ω: 150°C - 18.9°C = 131.1°C Max ambient
- 5.8 Ω: 84mW * 145 °C/W = 137.8°C Max ambient
- 3 Ω: 43mW * 145 °C/W = 143.8°C Max ambient
- 1.9 Ω: 27mW * 145 °C/W = 146.1°C Max ambient.

Now these maximum ambient temperatures are basically theoretical upper limits. You don't want to be operating near these ambient temperatures because there will be some additional heat from the chip controller that will contribute to temperature rise not included in the equations. So from experience, your going to want 20 or 30°C margin (more is even better from a reliability standpoint). So even with some temp rise lost due to my safety factor, you will still be able to operate any one of these varieties in an ambient condition over 100°C. That means any "normal" indoor environment is extremely comfortable for these devices with your provided load.

To be completely honest, one, I wouldn't use this chip; I never heard of this company before. That's my own bias and the chip may in fact be beautiful. And two, the seasoned engineers will realize I did the math "backwards". Normally, you would start with your ambient first, and then work your way back to the maximum permissible R<sub>DS(on)</sub> and select a device from there. Or also, to figure out "how much of a load can I use use for this ambient?" However, I presented it this way so you can better see the derivation (4 different times) so (hopefully) you get a better understanding.

Comment: You cannot neglect the chips supply current here. Datasheet states 0.4 mA from the HV supply without any switching activity. At 325V that makes 130 mW. It is not clear from the datasheet how much this increases with switching operation and if higher Rds variants provide significant advantage due to lower gate driver losses.

Comment: @LarsHankeln you can neglect it from the MOSFET heat budget. It's true that the chip supply current contributes to the overall power dissipation, but that's separate from the MOSFET calculations. Even with worst-case 130mW + 130mW , that's a little over half of the 450mW IC max abs power dissipation.

Comment: The point is that there is no information of how much it might increase with switching activity. Overall I agree with you, I would not use this chip.

Comment: @LarsHankein True. But being that the original question was about variations in RDSON, I didn't include the higher-order effects like switching losses and how the PCB  layout could help heatsink the chip. You can only assume a switching device like this will be high-effiency with PFC (as the datasheet claims). There will be other heating effects external to the chip that will also contribute to temp rise such as the freewheel diode and inductor. Even the enclosure the whole circuit goes in will matter. But you can only draft an answer based on the information provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time. Above discussion is very important to me.